# Get the wget title away(and keep my own)

Tags: batch-file

I have a batchfile and it contents this code:

```
Title Updater
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
wget -q -OUpdate.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip --no-check-certificate
```

The title "Updater" is showing the first five seconds and then when it starts to download, it changes to a wget title.
Here. Take a look(a pictuer of my almost-complete program).:
[image: Picture: Screenshot of the command line while wget is in use]

All I want is to keep the "Updater" title.

Could somebody help me please?

EDIT:
This is the whole code shown on the picture. All written by myself(Don't ask me why it is written this way! Do not try to steal it or shorter it, because it works the way it is!):

-SOURCE REMOVED-

Comment: Please don't put tag information in the title, and especially don't [bracket] that information. Brackets in titles are used for a specific purpose here. Also, you could do mobile users a favor and crop the graphic you use to the minimum size that's needed to illustrate the problem - there is no need here to include the entire black area of the window. Large graphics are hard to see on mobile devices and waste data for which mobile users are charged. You could have shown the problem with an image about 1/4th of the size easily.

Comment: I just need the correct script

Comment: Please read what I wrote again. I didn't ask what you need; your question does that quite well. I'm asking you to please be more considerate of other users in the future when you ask questions here.

Comment: If you try the code you've provided us, you'll see that your three lines do _not_, in fact, alter the title. Please test the code you provide before you post to ensure that your code example is [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In my long code it does. But this site won't allow me that many characters.
Well, check the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect solution you are looking for, but if you want a 'quick fix', then this could help you out.

if you simply change this code

```
:continue1
cls
Title Downloading...
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN (`wget -S --spider --no-check-certificate %URL% 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR "Content-Length: "`) DO (
    SET SIZE=%%A
)
```

into

```
:continue1
cls
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN (`wget -S --spider --no-check-certificate %URL% 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR "Content-Length: "`) DO (
    SET SIZE=%%A
)
Title Downloading...
```

Then the title will display `Downloading`.

The downside to this quick fix is that the wget title will be displayed for a fraction of a second.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove the ''downloading'' title... It's there because I was merging two batch files. Sorry about that.

Comment: I see.
I can't test this at the moment (No windows machine around).
But if you take a look at the line 
`%%A IN ('wget -S --spider --no-check-certificate %URL% 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR "Content-Length: "')`

There is no `-q` flag. Meaning that the wget call does not do it quietly. What happens if you add a `-q` flag?

Comment: It will exit when I start it with the -q parameter :/

Comment: Ah. I believe that might have something to do with the fact that you are trying to grab something from the output of thar wget call. So by using -q you don't get that output. Looks like the quick fix is your best shot at this moment :)

Comment: It really does crash or whatever it does...
With that flag...
Try it yourself and you'll se. Maybe you'll find the problem.

Comment: Yea. I know. And i explained why. You cant get something if it isnt there :)

Comment: maybe if there is another way to get a size of a file on dropbox.. then It may work

Comment: I guess you could add it to the text file. And ask for if the user wants to download a file that is xx.mb large as well.

Comment: Nah. Still the same. It says something about invalind number(I have my system in Czech language, so I down't know what it looks like in english)...

Answer (score 0):

Credits: [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708566/stop-wget-from-editing-the-title)

As per [wget source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/http.c#n3933) it changes the title on Windows unless `--no-verbose` option is given.

So the only way to keep the title AND see the progress is to launch `wget` in a separate [minimized] window, for example:

```
start /min /wait wget http://url
```