# Stop wget from editing the title

Tags: batch-file, wget

I am having problems with wget. When I am downloading something with wget, it shows the url in the progressbar. I want to set my own title and hold it. It's similar to this question: [Get the wget title away(and keep my own)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731536/get-the-wget-title-awayand-keep-my-own)

code:

```
title hello
wget http://www.white.nl/custom/img/slides/slide2/glow.png
```

how can I block wget from editing the title? -q shows nothing and with -nv it wont show the progress anymore, which I want to see

Comment: If it's similar to the question that you linked, how is it different?

Comment: @SomethingDark It wasn't answered and there was a lot of confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [wget source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/http.c#n3933) it changes the title on Windows unless `--no-verbose` option is given.

So the only way to keep the title AND see the progress is to launch `wget` in a separate [minimized] window, for example:

```
start /min /wait wget http://url
```